# Adding a clipping path to a UIImage, saving the clipped version to the Documents folder, and then showing it

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cgcontext, graphicscontext

In my app, the user starts out with a UIImage. Based on user input, the app creates a clipping path around a certain part of the image. I then want to be able to save that clipped version to the app's Documents directory so that it can be shown at a later time.

As far as I can tell, all of that is going smoothly *except* showing the clipped image at a later time. As soon as I try showing the image (by adding a custom view), I get a variety of `invalid context` errors, as well as a `message sent to deallocated instance`. While I'm not sure what's causing the last one, it's the `invalid context` ones that I'm most concerned about because the concept of a graphics context is not something I'm at all comfortable with.

Here are the exact errors:

```
<Error>: CGBitmapContextSetData: invalid context 0x4b997b0
<Error>: CGContextGetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x4b997b0
<Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x4b997b0
<Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x4b997b0
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorSpace: invalid context 0x4b997b0
<Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace: invalid context 0x4b997b0
*** -[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4b997b0
```

At this point, I'm going to post the code that creates the clipping path, then the code that attempts to save the context with the clipped image as a new image, and finally the code that is trying to show the image again. As I said above, I don't get an error until I try to show the image again.

Create clipping path:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{   
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    //Create clippingPath
    UIBezierPath *edgePath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    NSValue *firstPt = [edgePts objectAtIndex:0];

    [edgePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake([firstPt CGPointValue].x / scaleRatio, [firstPt CGPointValue].y / scaleRatio + 20)];
    [edgePts removeObject:firstPt];

    for (NSValue *pt in edgePts) {
        [edgePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake([pt CGPointValue].x / scaleRatio, [pt CGPointValue].y / scaleRatio + 20)];
    }

    clippingPath = edgePath;

    [clippingPath addClip];

    [img drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 20)];

    clippedContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(clippedContext);

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

Pretty much everything I'm doing with contexts and contextRefs above is total magic to me. It's something I pieced together from other posts here at SO and have basically no idea what any of it is doing. Shocking that I ended up with all those context errors, huh? ;)

Saving the image and then trying to display it immediately (erros occur on final line):

```
- (void)saveCutout
{
    CGImageRef clippedImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(imageView.clippedContext);
    CGContextRelease(imageView.clippedContext);
    UIImage *clippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:clippedImageRef];
    CGImageRelease(clippedImageRef);

    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(clippedImage);
    NSString *imgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/1.png", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];
    [imgData writeToFile:imgPath atomically:NO];

    //just testing to make sure it worked. first I hide the other two visible views
    imageView.hidden = YES;
    includedFrameView.hidden = YES;

    UIImage *newImg = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgPath] retain];
    ShowImage *imgView = [[ShowImage alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480) andImage:newImg];

    [self.view addSubview:imgView]; //ERRORS occur once this line runs

}
```

The `ShowImage` class is a simple `UIView` subclass. All it does is get initialized with the specified `UIImage`, and it's `drawRect:` method is the following:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [img drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 20)];
}
```

It's worth noting that the errors occur even before the single line in the `drawRect:` method above even gets called (I've tried putting a break point on that line but the app crashes first).

I know it's a lot of code, but that's because I don't even know where to start debugging this one. Along with solving my particular issue, I'd love an answer that more broadly addresses my use/misuse of contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new context for your drawing, then ending it when you are done doing your drawing. This might fix your context errors.

```
CGSize mySize = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mySize);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// The rest of your code goes here...

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Should that code go in the drawRect method in the block of code I posted under "Create clipping path" ? I tried that but now nothing shows up.